# Asp.net MVC: Map path to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am posting a form to url /Admin/EditInPlace from page /About
In EditInPlace's conroller code i can find the Url-Referrer i.e. from which page request is coming. But how can i map the Url-Referrer to its View page??

In short how can i found that a page /xyz is mapping to which View.aspx file programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needing to know what View the user was previously looking at smells like a design problem. As a workaround, consider passing a query string parameter to the Admin controller's EditInPlace method that describes which UI the user just saw.

```
/Admin/EditInPlace?channel=basic
```

Comment: +1 And how can you develop a RESTful application with those sorts of dependencies?